# Linq to sql ! operator for nullable of type int

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, linq-to-sql, and-operator

sql column `ReadershipLevels` - `int` with null

`level` is local `int` type variable

`&` is `bitwise` operator

Linq to SQL

```
 vAdvanceSearchResults = from t 
                         in vAdvanceSearchResults 
                         where (t.ReadershipLevels & level) > 0 
                         select t;
```

if `level = 32`

Above Linq query generated the SQL like below:

```
SELECT [t2].[ReadershipLevels],[t2].[ID], [t2].[ISBN], [t2].[IsHighlighted], [t2].[Title], 
FROM (

    SELECT DISTINCT [t1].[ID], [t1].[ISBN], [t1].[IsHighlighted], [t1].[Title], [t1].[SuluAuthors], 
    FROM [dbo].[udf_SearchDWSearch]('swim', 'ALL') AS [t0]
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[DWSearch] AS [t1] ON [t0].[DWSearchID] = ([t1].[ID])
    WHERE [t1].[DatePublished] < '2016/05/27'
    ) AS [t2]
    WHERE ([t2].[ReadershipLevels] & 32) >0
    order by [t2].[ReadershipLevels]
```

I want to include a `not` So I made like below

```
not ([t2].[ReadershipLevels] & 32) > 0



SELECT DISTINCT [t1].[ID], [t1].[ISBN], [t1].[IsHighlighted], [t1].[Title], [t1].[SuluAuthors], 
        FROM [dbo].[udf_SearchDWSearch]('swim', 'ALL') AS [t0]
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[DWSearch] AS [t1] ON [t0].[DWSearchID] = ([t1].[ID])
        WHERE [t1].[DatePublished] < '2016/05/27'
        ) AS [t2]
        WHERE not ([t2].[ReadershipLevels] & 32) >0
        order by [t2].[ReadershipLevels]
```

Which is working fine.

Now I want to change same in LINQ to SQL also

```
vAdvanceSearchResults = from t 
                        in vAdvanceSearchResults 
                        where ! (t.ReadershipLevels & level) > 0 
                        select t;
```

But the above throwing error- cannot apply operator ! to operand of type System.Nullable

Changed to -

```
vAdvanceSearchResults = from t 
                        in vAdvanceSearchResults 
                        where ! (t.ReadershipLevels.Value & level) > 0 
                        select t;
```

Throwing error- Cannot apply operator `!` to operand of type `int`

How can I add a `!` operator in my `LINQ` query?

Comment: Why you want `!` here. you can check like this also `(t.ReadershipLevels.Value & level) < 0`. Not greater than 0 means it's less than zero.

Comment: sorry i want to exclude all records with 32 , so using not.

Comment: (t.ReadershipLevels.Value & level) < 0 results empty set, I want to exclude records with level = 32.

Comment: Are you trying to exclude results where `t.ReadershipLevels.Value & level` == 32?

Comment: that is bitwise operator, trying to exclude all results t.ReadershipLevels.Value & level above 32

Comment: not ([t2].[ReadershipLevels] & 32) > 0  works fine in sql, i want to include that "not" condition to my linq to sql query.

Comment: you can do like this `where t.ReadershipLevels.Value != level && t.ReadershipLevels.Value > 0` I think it's enough

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work for you. You don't need to use & operator

```
vAdvanceSearchResults = from t 
                        in vAdvanceSearchResults 
                        where t.ReadershipLevels.Value != level && t.ReadershipLevels.Value > 0 
                        select t;
```

Answer (score 1):

try changing :  `where ! (t.ReadershipLevels.Value & level) > 0` 
to this :   `where ! ((t.ReadershipLevels.Value & level) > 0 )`

Answer (score 1):

Why do we need a bitwise operator here?

As mentioned in your question if you use that condition,

```
not ([t2].[ReadershipLevels] & 32) > 0
```

it will retrieve all results with ReadershipLevels value in 
(1 to 31),(64 to 95),(128 to 159) and so on.

If you really want to show the records like in that range mentioned above you can use like below as `not ([t2].[ReadershipLevels] & 32) > 0` is same as checking it equals 0,

```
vAdvanceSearchResults = from t 
                    in vAdvanceSearchResults 
                    where (t.ReadershipLevels.Value & level) == 0 
                    select t;
```

Or if you don't want to show records with readershiplevels value "32" then do simple checking as,

```
vAdvanceSearchResults = from t 
                    in vAdvanceSearchResults 
                    where (t.ReadershipLevels ?? 0) != 32 
                    select t;
```

Hope it helps